# EF Core Specifying foriegn key to reference table that has values from enumeration

Tags: ef-core-2.1

Let's say I have the following entity.

```
public class TestData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public TestType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Test Type is an enumeration, but I would like to have a reference table in the database with the values of the enumeration.  To do this, I create a TestTypeEntry entity which is created by EF core and seed it from values in the TestType enumeration.

```
public class TestTypeEntry
{
    public int TestTypeEntryID { get; set; }
    public String TestTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I simply want to create a foreign key constraint between TestData.Type (the enumeration) and the TestTypeID of the test type entry table using the fluent API.

This problem is seems to be the result of using enumerations as values for an entity and wanting to have a reference table in the database that reflects these values with a foreign key relationship to it. Unless I'm going about this in the wrong way, all I'm missing is creating a foreign key constraint to the reference table using the fluent API. Something like

```
Entity<TestData>(td => td.Type).HasForeignKey<TestTypeEntity>(tt => tt.TestTypeEntryID)
```

I know the above code doesn't work (just trying to give an idea of what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EnumToNumberConverter` [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

Something along the lines of:

```
var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<TestType>();

modelBuilder
    .Entity<TestData>()
    .Property( td => td.Type )
    .HasConversion( converter );
```

Edit:

After comments, I understand the problem to be that you have the table to be enumerated in your `DbContext` but simply wish to use an `Enum` to assign values.  First, as described in the comments, I don't like that decision as it requires maintenance of data in two locations - the DB table and the `Enum` code.

However, you can accomplish what you want by using a foreign key property alone without a navigation property, marking the setter as `private` and then using an EF-ignored property of the `Enum` type to handle conversion to and from the `Enum`:

```
public class TestData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    // FK, private setter
    public int TestTypeEntryId { get; private set; }
    // enum property that EF will ignore
    public TestType Type
    {
        get => ( TestType )TestTypeEntryId;
        set => TestTypeEntryId = ( int )value;
    }
}
```

Model configuration for `TestData`

```
        builder.HasOne<TestTypeEntry>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( d => d.TestTypeEntryId );

        builder.Ignore( d => d.Type );
```

Do note that using an `Enum` does not prevent invalid values from being set.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not sure how this helps me create a foreign key in the database.  I'll try to reword the question so it's a bit more clear.

Comment: @Geekn - I don't follow; are you saying that EF is creating your table in the database but you want to have it reference a table that already exists outside of your EF model's domain?

Comment: Not exactly.  I reworded it again : ).

Comment: @Geekn - so what you're looking for is a way to create and populate a table for enums referenced by your other entities.  I had a similar idea a few years ago but ultimately scrapped it as it leads to the need to maintain the data in multiple locations and possible data inconsistencies.  I'd suggest creating the entity for the "enum" table and statically caching ID values that you can then reference via static class properties in a similar fashion to how you use `Enum` values.

Comment: Yea but I'm almost there.  Seems strange that I cannot simply create a foreign key constraint on some other table using fluent API (especially if that table is actually in the data context).

Comment: @Geekn did you ever solve this problem? it seems like a common use case and I'm stumbling into the same issue.